# How to find out if some sound recording is real or computer generated?

Tags: voice, voice-manipulation, authentic

I would like to learn if there are any reliable methods to find out if some human voice recording is real or computer generated.

The voice recording under suspect is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cvf4aeRLu0E). The voice recording contains evidence for some corruption charges. The recording is probably obtained by unauthorized wiretapping. The accused people deny the authenticity of the voice recording.

Is there any reliable methods to find out if this voice recording is computer generated or assembled sound or not?

Answer (score 2):

Compare similar phenoms like eh uh pt zk you know. If a lot of them are identical it might be Computer generated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would need to find a Turkish forensic audio expert (but maybe you are that expert?). Someone who knows the equipment supposedly used to make this recording and whether those digital artifacts we are hearing are caused by the equipment or the result of faking the voices.

Even with the noise and the artifacts, it sounds random enough to me in terms of dynamics and such, that I would guess it was real. But then I am no expert and don't understand the language at all...

It's a pretty interesting question!

Answer (score -1):

These days, it's nearly impossible to tell. Good luck.